# Getting workbooks from MS Word in C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

In my application, I created excel workbooks in microsoft word document using this code :

```
wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject("MSGraph.Chart.8", excellApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Then I need to get that excel workbooks from word document, how can i do that?

I also tried:

```
Word.InlineShapes shapes = wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes;
```

However, shapescount equals to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word.InlineShapes shapes = wordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes;

should work